# NSMutableArray is empty after addObject

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I want to add an object into an NSMutableArray:

```
NSLog(@"Object text: %@", object.text);
NSLog(@"Object: %@", object);
[appdelegate.objects addObject:object];
NSLog(@"Objects array size: %i", [appdelegate.objects count]);
```

This is the output:

```
Object text: This is the text
Object: <Object: 0x6e762c0>
Objects array size: 0
```

How is this possible, I add an object, on the next line, it is still empty. The `NSMutableArray` is not `nil`, because that would raise an exception.

Anybody a guess?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would not raise an exception if it was `nil`. You can still message a `nil` object if it usually responds to that message. In this case, you'll just get 0. I think you're not allocating the array. Make sure you're doing this:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

As a debugging tip, if you're unsure about the state of an object and want to make sure the object indeed exists and is ready to be used, use `assert(appdelegate.objects);` If the array is nil, your code will stop executing at this line. If it doesn't stop at this line, then you know the object exists in memory.

Comment: It was indeed null. Used a demo example which also didn't alloc / init the array, but that was a working example. How could that possibly work?

Comment: @TomWebDev hmm it couldn't possibly work. It had to have been allocated somewhere, maybe the code is just hard to spot. Do you have a link to the example?

Comment: Probably the array was created with arrayWithCapacity? Because you will then not find any allocation of the array.

Comment: @mohabitar ah you are right again, but it's allocated in another class. I think that's weird but maybe that's just my Java background. :) Thanks for helping me out!
Edit: this tutorial by the way: http://buildmobile.com/parsing-xml-files-with-objective-c/#fbid=pOZvmtCbJRc

Answer (score 0):

Your NSMutableArray is indeed almost certainly null. It won't raise an exception, because sending any message to `nil` in ObjC is a no-op and would behave as you're seeing, with a return value of zero or `nil`, etc.

Try logging that as well to double check.